# Map the split to trim each entry

Tags: rust

I need to write a function that takes a string as an input, splits it by the line break character and trims all the redundant break characters in each entry of the split. I've come up with the following:

```
fn split_and_trim(text: &String) {
    let lines - text.split('\n').map(|l| String::from(l).trim());
    println!("{:?}", lines)
}
```

But this code returns me the following error:

```
6 |     let lines = text.map(|l| String::from(l).trim());
  |                                   ---------------^^^^^^^
  |                                   |
  |                                   returns a reference to data owned by the current function
  |                                   temporary value created here
```

Trying to rewrite it the following way:

```
let lines: Vec<String> = text.split('\n').map(|l| String::from(l).trim()).collect();
```

Returns another error:

```
value of type `Vec<String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`
```

What would be the correct way of achieving this goal (splitting the string and trimming the each element)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e49fa670422a02d2033de545f5239c2e)?

Comment: @jsejcksn it worked, thank you! Could you please post this as an answer,so I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create new `String`s here, since `trim` only needs slices. [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5bea0fd01ca7746b8ba4d9b16b746001)

```rs
fn split_and_trim(text: &str) {
    let lines: Vec<&str> = text.split('\n').map(|l| l.trim()).collect();
    println!("{:?}", lines)
}
```

You should also take `&str` instead of `&String` as a function parameter in almost all cases.

If you need `String`s, you can convert them after trimming.